# Pra que servem e quais as diferenças entre Grunt x Gulp?

Tags: grunt, gulpjs, bower

Já ouvi falar muito de Grunt e Gulp, porém ainda não entendi pra que funcionam eles exatamente. as minhas dúvidas, são as seguintes:

- Pra que eles servem?
- Existe alguma relação entre eles?
- Eles podem ser comparados ao bower, por exemplo?
- Teria algum exemplo de como/ou quando usar um ou outro?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> *Pra que eles servem?*

De modo simples e resumido, ambos servem para automatizar e simplificar o seu fluxo de trabalho e processos.

Por exemplo, eu utilizo `Grunt` para fazer o processo dos meus arquivos em `SASS` e gerar um `CSS` minificado, sem ter que copiar meu arquivo, enviar para um serviço online para minificar, ou pior (e muito menos provável), fazer na mão. Outro exemplo, seria a concatenação de arquivos `JS`, enviar seus arquivos para uma hospedagem online através de uma conexão `ftp`, etc. São diversas opções.

> *Existe alguma relação entre eles?*

Sim e não. Sim, pois ambos possuem a mesma finalidade, automatizar e simplificar processos. Não pois o modo como são feitos diferem um do outro e ai a questão muda bastante, pois começa a entrar mais em uma questão de preferência do que qual é melhor.

> *Eles podem ser comparados ao bower, por exemplo?*

Não. `Bower` está para ser comparado com `NPM`. Ambos são gerenciadores de pacotes, por exemplo, você irá usá-los para fazer download de um plugin, enquanto `grunt` ou `gulp` será usado para processos (ou tarefas) dentro desses plugins. `Bower` e `NPM` teriam mais como finalidade você fazer download do `bootstrap`, por exemplo, verificar a versão e manter atualizado, tudo isso sem precisar ir de fato ao site do `bootstrap` e fazer isso manualmente.

> *Teria algum exemplo de como/ou quando usar um ou outro?*

Como já citado nas respostas acima, mas só para reforçar. Existem diversas tarefas que eles podem executar, vou citar as que eu mais uso através do `Grunt`:

- Concatenar e processar arquivos de `SASS` e `Compass`;
- Remover classes não usadas de um arquivo `CSS` quando comparado aos arquivos `html`;
- Minificar o arquivo `CSS` e fazer compressão em `gzip`;
- Concatenar e minificar arquivos `JS`;
- Compactar o projeto e executar upload para uma conexão `ftp`, colocando o projeto online;

Ou seja, todo esse processo é executado automaticamente pelo `Grunt`. Eu só preciso executar a linha de comando, exemplo `grunt execBuild` (baseado nas minhas configurações e pacotes) e todas essas tarefas serão executadas automaticamente. Então você pode ver um exemplo bem prático, funcional e que automatiza bastante as tarefas.

Já imaginou fazer isso tudo na mão?

Comment: Excelente! Muito boa resposta!